# Using stepAIC or comparable function in R, estimating best-fit lm output and estimating to get summary

Tags: r, regression

simple question from a new R user - I'm trying to use stepAIC across several different regression models, and I want to find out how to save/estimate a regression based on the output for the best fit "Call" from stepAIC.  Is there a way to do this?  Thank you,  any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned from stepAIC has classes "aov" and "lm", so it will respond to all of the functions that an ordinary result from `lm` would respond to.

```
library(MASS)   # running first example on the help page:
quine.hi <- aov(log(Days + 2.5) ~ .^4, quine)
quine.nxt <- update(quine.hi, . ~ . - Eth:Sex:Age:Lrn)
quine.stp <- stepAIC(quine.nxt,
    scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
    trace = FALSE)
```

So this is its class value and then it `print`-ed appearance at the console, although obviously not all of its components. You can use `names` to find those and get further information with `summary`:

```
> class(quine.stp)
[1] "aov" "lm" 
> quine.stp
Call:
   aov(formula = log(Days + 2.5) ~ Eth + Sex + Age + Lrn + Eth:Sex + 
    Eth:Age + Eth:Lrn + Sex:Age + Sex:Lrn + Age:Lrn + Eth:Sex:Lrn + 
    Eth:Age:Lrn, data = quine)

Terms:
                     Eth      Sex      Age      Lrn  Eth:Sex  Eth:Age  Eth:Lrn
Sum of Squares  10.68203  0.62388  3.76424  0.65290  0.01533  5.98964  0.01246
Deg. of Freedom        1        1        3        1        1        3        1
                 Sex:Age  Sex:Lrn  Age:Lrn Eth:Sex:Lrn Eth:Age:Lrn Residuals
Sum of Squares   8.68925  0.57977  2.38640     4.69558     2.09602  66.59962
Deg. of Freedom        3        1        2           1           2       125

Residual standard error: 0.7299294
2 out of 23 effects not estimable
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the above reply, it was very informative!  I found a quick and easy solution, as well, which is to use the `lm.beta` library, which stores the coefficients with low p-values.